# Checking whether an edge exists in a Graph

Tags: julia

What is the preferred method for checking whether an edge exists in a graph in the Graphs.jl package?

Say we have a GenericGraph G and we want to check if an edge a->b is in the Graph. I would like to have something similar to `has_edge(G, a, b)` but that does not appear to exist.

I am currently using `in(a, in_neighbors(b, G))` to check, but that may be quite inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand it, that *is* the normal way to check for an edge in a graph. It's not really inefficient either.