# Directed Graphs in Julia, need some function like "has_edge"

Tags: graph, network-programming, julia, directed-graph

I have to initialize a directed Graph in Julia and i am searching for a procedure testing, if a node has a specific neighbour.

In Python you have a graph Class where you can call a function like:
DirectedGraph.has_edge(i, j) -> true if i and j are connected

I have not found s.th. similar in Julia. Can somebody show me a way, how to implement this in Julia?
Currently i am using Graphs.jl, i think it is the most extensively package.

Comment: Have you looked at [Graphs.jl](http://graphsjl-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27004932/checking-whether-an-edge-exists-in-a-graph

Comment: Yup, just wanted to link the two and show that this is still an open question.

Comment: @AlexA. yes i have read the Docs

Comment: @MattB. thank you for linking to this question. Pity that there is no solution until now...

Comment: A good solution was posted in the question---use `in(a, in_neighbors...)`

Comment: @team17 Are you using Graphs.jl? Or some other library. You need to state the library in the question (unless it is some core julia graph class I haven't heard of)

Comment: @Oxinabox Yes, i am using Graphs.jl. At the moment i am using in(a, in_neighbors(b, G)) like in the other question. I think ist the only possibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In relation to question [Checking whether an edge exists in a Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27004932/checking-whether-an-edge-exists-in-a-graph), i think the only acceptable possibility is to use the following expression to check if a node i is a neighbor of node j in a graph g:

```
in(i, neighbors(j, g))
```

Answer (score 4):

Just wanted to follow up here - `has_edge` exists in LightGraphs.jl for both directed and undirected graphs.

Edited to add: As of this post, Graphs.jl has been moved to the "JuliaArchive" organization indicating that development has stagnated. LightGraphs.jl is the preferred graphs package for Julia.